# Searching entity by another entity as criteria

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data

I'm havin simple relationship between entities:

```
class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private double calories;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn
    private Category category;
}

class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And I'm using following repository

```
interface ProductRepository extends Repository<Product, Long> {
    Product save(Product product);
    Page<Product> findAll(Pageable pageable);
    Page<Product> findByCategory(Pageable pageable, Category category);
    void delete(Product product);
}
```

Which is invoked in `facade` like this

```
 public Page<ProductDTO> getProductsByCategory(Pageable pageable, String categoryName) {
        return productRepository.findByCategory(pageable, dtoConverter.toCategory(categoryName))
                .map(Product::toDTO);
    }
```

and in `dtoConverter`

```
Category toCategory(String categoryName) {
        return new Category(categoryName);
    }
```

Which finnaly leads us to `Controller`

```
@GetMapping("/findCategory")
    Page<ProductDTO> getProductsByCategory(Pageable pageable, @RequestParam String categoryName) {
        return productFacade.getProductsByCategory(pageable, categoryName);
    }
```

I'v got very similar way to get and create new products, it works, but once I try to find product by category the way I described above, I got

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-11-30T22:57:29.660+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/products/findCategory=fruit"
}
```

Even tho I'm sure there are Products of this category stored in db (I find them looking directly at mysql and by using findAll endpoint). Anyone can explain me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in the following snippet.

```
Category toCategory(String categoryName) {
    return new Category(categoryName);
}
```

You can't just create a new object. You need to return an object that has a reference to the database table. So first you need to retrieve the category object from the database, then return it.

Thus you would create a CategoryRepository :

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends Repository<Category,Long> {
    Category findByName(String name);
}
```

And then in your method:

```
Category toCategory(String categoryName) {
    return categoryRepository.findByName(categoryName);
}
```

---

*Side note : you could extend JpaRepository, instead of Repository, which will give a couple of handy methods.*

Answer (score 0):

Since your category name is unique you could change your repository method to

```
interface ProductRepository extends Repository<Product, Long> {
    Product save(Product product);
    Page<Product> findAll(Pageable pageable);
    Page<Product> findByCategory_Name(Pageable pageable, String categoryName);
    void delete(Product product);
}
```

and use it in your getProductsByCategory method

```
public Page<ProductDTO> getProductsByCategory(Pageable pageable, String categoryName) 
{
    return productRepository.findByCategory_Name(pageable, categoryName))
            .map(Product::toDTO);
}
```